# LC Resonance with Inductor with Solid Metal core

Tags: capacitor, homework, resonance, physics, induction

Consider inductor with air gap and solid metal core made from material with relative magnetic permeability 1 regardless of temperature (such as copper or aluminium).

There is Air gap between coil and metal core.

Please also consider Eddy currents in the solid metal core.

[image: FIG.1]

Ref.
[https://www.amazon.com/Ductor-Magnetic-Induction-Automotive-Flameless/dp/B07KWQDYZY#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KWQDYZY)

The inductor is connected with capacitor in:

Series LC circuit

Parallel LC circuit

Is it possible under certain values of frequency and capacitance to obtain LC resonance with high Q factor?

Q above 20 for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to get high Q out of such a resonator due to the imperfect coupling between the primary (coil) and secondary (the piece of metal, which is effectively a shorted one-turn winding).

Let's draw it using the equivalent circuit of a non-ideal transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM6XFr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we can move the load resistance to the primary side by transforming it appropriately:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJanvw.png)</sup>

Finally, if we use a very low resistance metal, the magnetizing resistance will be shorted out. Let's set `Rmetal_pri=0` and see what happens:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feFqDQ.png)</sup>

We're left with an ideal LC resonator *without* any losses if the metal "core" placed in the coil is perfectly conductive. This happens because the magnetizing inductance of the transformer that's created this way is shorted out completely, leaving only the leakage inductance. In this case, the Q factor is only limited by the ESR of the coil and capacitor.

In general, the resonator behaves as follows: With no metal inserted, the Q factor is high as the secondary of the transformer is effectively open. The total inductance is `Lleak + Lmag`. With somewhat resistive metal in the coil, the Q factor will drop. However, as you make the metal more conductive, the Q factor will actually *rise* again as the magnetizing inductance is shorted out, leaving only `Lleak` to resonate. This also means that the resonant frequency will increase with metal inserted, and it will become higher the more conductive that metal is.

This is also how LLC resonant converters work. (They're a special type of switchmode power supplies.)

If you find that the Q factor of your setup is too low, you can increase it by making the magnetic coupling between the coil and the metal worse. You can achieve this, for example, by making the coil physically larger.

However, if you want to transfer as much energy as possible from the resonator into the metal, the goal is actually to have a Q factor that's *as low as possible*.

Comment: Thank you. Let's consider the LC setup is constant. The metal is inserted in Inductor before switch on the LC circuit.  I am able to change only the input frequency and to change the value for Capacitors . Is it possible under some combination of input Frequency and Capacitor value to obtain Q above 20 for example.

Comment: @Fan Yes, but you'll have to measure the circuit's parameters first. You need to know the coil's inductance, coupling factor, load resistance, and (of course) the number of turns. You might be able to get these values with an LCR meter. Once you have those values, you can use them to compute the circuit's characteristics. Why do you even need a high Q in the first place? (Higher Q means lower energy transfer to the metal piece, and therefore less heating of the metal.)